# Random links in embed code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small embed code for a video.

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" scrolling="no" src="http://link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to create a button which will randomly select from an array of links and makes it as a "src" in the code above.

Basically a random video generator.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try ? Can you precise what part didn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an ID on the iframe and not set any SRC (or have one by default). And have a button that will fill it.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="randomVideo()">Random video</button>
<iframe src="" id="video" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then you'd have your array of links, and a function that will choose a random one

**JS**

```
var links = [ "link1", "link2", "link3" ];
var random = 0;

// If you want a random video to be chosen on page load
randomVideo();

function randomVideo() {
    var temp = random;
    // Make sure we do not display the same video twice in a row
    while(temp == random) temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
    random = temp;
    document.getElementById("video").src = links[random];
}
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: thank you, i was able to get it working, but your answer works as well :)